# Using vertical lines in title page

Tags: titles

I'm trying to replicate this title page made in Word, so far so good, problem is that placing vertical lines moves all the text to the next page. I've tried surrounding both lines and text with parbox and minipage to no avail. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

[image: Desired effect]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}


\usepackage[paperheight=27.94cm,paperwidth=21.59cm,left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


\graphicspath{ {imagenes/} }

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{-2cm}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=13.25cm,height=1.77cm]{portada/secretaria}
    \end{figure}
    
    % \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
    % \rule{\textwidth}{6pt}
    % \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
    \hrule height 3pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 3pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
    
    \hspace{12pt}
    \vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 3pt
    \hspace{-1pt}
    \vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 6pt
    \hspace{-1pt}
    \vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 3pt
    
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{DIVISIÓN DE ESTUDIOS asdf POSGRADO}
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{0.2\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont OPCIÓN 1.- TESIS \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{TRABAJO PROFESIONAL}
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{``NOMBRE DE LA TESIS''}
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{QUE PARA OBTENER EL GRADO DE:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DOCTOR EN CIENCIAS} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DE LA INGENIERÍA}
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{PRESENTA:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DIRECTOR DE TESIS:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL DIRECTOR DE TESIS
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{CODIRECTOR DE TESIS:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL CODIRECTOR DE TESIS
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=2.9cm,height=3.07cm]{portada/ito_logo}
    \end{figure}
    
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ORIZABA, VERACRUZ, MÉXICO \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ MES AÑO
    \end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[[image: portada fea2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a `\vspace{-15cm}` just before your text produces something looking like your word doc template. Something like this (you might want to adjust the value I used):

```
% header above %
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=13.25cm,height=1.77cm]{portada/secretaria}
\end{figure}

% \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
% \rule{\textwidth}{6pt}
% \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
\hrule height 3pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule height 6pt depth 0pt width \textwidth
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule height 3pt depth 0pt width \textwidth

\hspace{12pt}
\vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 3pt
\hspace{-1pt}
\vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 6pt
\hspace{-1pt}
\vrule height 0.7\textheight depth 0pt width 3pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Change made here. Possibly adjust vspace value %%
\vspace*{-15cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
    \textbf{DIVISIÓN DE ESTUDIOS asdf POSGRADO}
\end{center}
% rest of document %
```

Comment: It works flawlessly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tcolorbox`](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox.pdf/0) package. Using the package add a new settings before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{siderules}[1][]{blanker, breakable, 
    left=3mm, right=3mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline west={6pt}{5pt}{black},
    borderline west={3pt}{13pt}{black},
    before upper=\indent, parbox=false, #1}
```

Then insert entire text into `\begin{siderules} ... \end{siderules}` tags.

For clarification I have added your code:

```
\begin{siderules}

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{DIVISIÓN DE ESTUDIOS POSGRADO}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{0.2\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont OPCIÓN 1.- TESIS \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{TRABAJO PROFESIONAL}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{``NOMBRE DE LA TESIS''}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{QUE PARA OBTENER EL GRADO DE:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DOCTOR EN CIENCIAS} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DE LA INGENIERÍA}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{PRESENTA:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO
    \end{center}

    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{DIRECTOR DE TESIS:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL DIRECTOR DE TESIS
    \end{center}

    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \textbf{CODIRECTOR DE TESIS:} \\
        \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont NOMBRE DEL CODIRECTOR DE TESIS
    \end{center}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=2.9cm,height=3.07cm]{portada/ito_logo}
    \end{figure}

    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ORIZABA, VERACRUZ, MÉXICO \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ MES AÑO
    \end{flushleft}

\end{siderules}
```